# How do I initiate client-side HTTP/2 streams with Netty 5 Alpha 2?

Tags: netty, http2

I'm trying to figure out how to use HTTP/2 streams with Netty 5.  I'm currently using the Alpha 2 release.  The example client does not set the stream ID in the message headers.  There doesn't appear to be a way to create a new client-initiated stream using the APIs.  Are clients meant to track streams and initiate new streams by creating a new message and attaching a new stream id to the message header?